# Changin OS parameters from Java source code

Tags: windows, linux, operating-system, hotkeys

Can I design my program so that it will automatically change OS's hotkeys parameters? I mean, when installing a program, it will set the hotkey of OS so that if you press them, the program itself would run.
(Linux/Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible on Windows if you use the Win32 API. This would work if you create an application in c++ for example which waits for a keyboard input, checks it and calls your java program if the hotkey was pressed. But I don't know any way to do this on Linux or in Java directly.

Answer (score 1):

If your app. has a GUI & you can distribute from a web site, look into [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS does not provide the 'hotkey' functionality specifically, but can install desktop shortcuts and menu items for Java applications.  JWS works on platforms which support Java.